# LM317T Simulation in Eagle giving an Error, unkown subckt

Tags: simulation, eaglecad

I am a beginner in Eagle and I am trying to do a simulation of the circuit attached to this post. I keep getting the same error and I have tried other solutions posted but the error remains. Anyone who can help me with this?

**This is the error:**
Error: unknown subckt: x_vr1 +24v n_6 n_11 lm317t
Note: No ".plot", ".print", or ".fourier" lines; no simulations run

I have some of the other chips working and I have followed the same approach but no success on this one.[image: Circuit to be simulated]

Thank you,

Comment: Resolution of your screenshot is too low. please upload a larger image.

Comment: Its telling you that you haven't included a model for the lm317t. I am not familiar with this particular tool, but there will be a way to include files with models for the parts that you are trying to simulate. You will need a model of the lm317t (often these are available to download from the manufacturer's website) and you will need to tell the simulator to use this model.

Comment: This is better suited for their forums/user support.